# Scala function definitions and usage

Tags: scala, lambda

Based on below examples of defining functions what is the best use of 2 and 3 in different scenarios?

1. `def sum(x: Int, y: Int): Int = { x+y }`
   This is a function definition with arguments, return type and function body
2. `val sum = (x: Int, y: Int) => { x+y }`
   This seems like an assignment of lambda function to a variable, why return type is never defined here?
3. `val sum: (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => { x+y }`
   This is defining a function as a type?
   **I don't understand how this works!**

All 3 functions when invoked will yield the same result:

`scala> sum(1,2)`
`Int = 3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. `def sum(x: Int, y: Int): Int = { x+y }`
>      This is a function definition with arguments, return type and function body

This is *not* a function definition. This is a *method* definition. Functions and methods are *fundamentally* different. Functions are objects, methods are not. (Methods *belong* to objects.) Methods can be polymorphic, functions can't.

> 1. `val sum = (x: Int, y: Int) => { x+y }`
>      This seems like an assignment of lambda function to a variable, why return type is never defined here?

Are you asking why the type of `sum` isn't declared or why the return type of the function literal isn't declared? The return type of the function literal isn't declared because there is no way in the syntax to do so. You simply *cannot* declare the return type of a function literal, it is always inferred. The type of `sum` isn't declared because it is not necessary: it can be inferred to be the same as the type of the function literal, i.e. `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`.

Think `val foo = "Hello"`.

> 1. `val sum: (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => { x+y }`
>      This is defining a function as a type?

No. This is the exact same thing as 2., except that here the type of `sum` is explicitly declared (as `(Int, Int) => Int` which is syntactic sugar for `Function[Int, Int, Int]`) instead of inferred. Since the type of `sum` is known, you can leave off the types of the function parameters, because they can be inferred from the context.

Think `val foo: String = "Hello"`.

Comment: Wait I'm confused... you're saying in (2) syntax doesn't allow for setting function type explicitly but in (3) you're saying it is the same as (2) but function type is set explicitly :) which means syntax allows for it.

Comment: According to the cheatsheet on scala-lang.org (1) is a function definition http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/

Comment: @marcin_koss: Sorry, that should have said "return type". You cannot declare the return type of a function literal, it is always inferred. If you don't use the function literal syntax, i.e. you explicitly create an anonymous subclass of `Function2` and manually implement the `apply` method, then it's a different story. In (3), you do *not* declare the return type of the function literal, you declare the type of the variable that the function literal is being assigned to be a function type with specific return type.

Comment: Thank you this clarified it!

Comment: @marcin_koss: That's wrong. It is well known that sometimes the term "function" is used incorrectly to refer to methods or to the common set of both methods functions. This even happens in the Scala Language Specification in some places. I would consider those bugs that need to be fixed. I believe they have mostly been fixed in the SLS, but apparently not in the documentation.

Comment: Hmm yes those terms are mixed very often although generally fundamental difference between function and method is that function is just a piece of abstracted code that is called by its name and method is a function that is associated with specific object and can operate on that object's data. So seems like Scala has different understanding of functions and methods?

Comment: We are talking about Scala here. In Scala, the terms "function" and "method" have precise meanings that are defined with mathematical rigor in the Scala Language Specification. It is unfortunate, that even within the very same document that defines them as clearly separate entities, they are mixed up. It is always in a context where there is no confusion, but still … using a term such as "subroutine" that doesn't have any specific meaning in Scala would be much better IMO. And in the link you quoted, it is clearly wrong. `def` defines a method, function literals define functions.

Comment: @marcin_koss, indeed it has. In Scala a function is just an instance of a class which extends certain trait (one from a family of classes `FunctionX`). Functions can be passed around and stored into variables. If you have C++ background, you can probably think of functions in Scala as *functors* in C++. Methods, on the other hand, are usual object-oriented methods, just as you defined them. In fact, on the low level functions are implemented in terms of methods (function is an object with a method called `apply`).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Unfortunately I don't have much background in C++ but I have a better understanding of this concept now, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In line 2, scala compiler inferences type of lambda function.

```
val sum = (x: Int, y: Int) => { x + y }
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          function value
```

**x** and **y** are type of Int, thus **x + y** is a Int type. In this case, type of **sum** is ***(Int, Int) => Int***.

In line 3, it shows the type of sum - ***(Int, Int) => Int***. **sum** indicates a function same with line 2.

```
val sum: (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => { x+y }
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         type                function value
```

Right side of **=** is function signature and body. It receives two arguments called **x** and **y**. Its body is **x + y**.

Shortly, line 2 and line 3 are equivalent. Line 2 has no type of function value, but scala can inference its type. Line 3 has type of function value explicitly, and omits argument type of signature of function value.

Answer (score 0):

this is about the difference between method and function. The useful link to show the difference is http://java.dzone.com/articles/revealing-scala-magician%E2%80%99s

I think in the 3rd way, you can understand it like a type T = (Int, Int) => Int and then do this : val sum: T = (x,y) => { x+y }

another thing is that if remove input arguments, method and function is different.

def sum: Int = { 3 } //call sum, get 3

val sum: () => Int = () => { 3 } //call sum, return a function, need to call sum() to get 3